# SQLite error (10): delayed 25ms for lock/sharing conflict

Tags: c#, sqlite, locking, conflict

My [C#/SQLite app](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync) works fine but outputs this error once in a while:

```
SQLite error (10): delayed 25ms for lock/sharing conflict
```

As suggested on [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/69721), I updated to the latest SQLite, but it still happens.
How to fix this?

---

SQLite version: `sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-Win32-2010-1.0.84.0.zip` at the `Precompiled Statically-Linked Binaries for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)` paragraph at http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Visual C# 2010 Express

Comment: Worth checking if you are enclosing your SqliteConnections in a using statement to ensure that they are disposed.

Comment: @GavinSinai: I haven't been able to pinpoint where it happens (because it seems to happen randomly) but I only use SQLite in this class: https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/blob/master/SparkleLib/Cmis/CmisDatabase.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this original code:

```
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(GetSQLiteConnection()))
    {
        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "DELETE FROM folders WHERE path='" + path + "'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            SparkleLogger.LogInfo("CmisDatabase", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Changing to this solved the problem (only the first two lines differ):

```
    var connection = GetSQLiteConnection();
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
    try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "DELETE FROM folders WHERE path='" + path + "'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            SparkleLogger.LogInfo("CmisDatabase", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code from your comment:

```
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(GetSQLiteConnection()))
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText =
                    "DELETE FROM folders WHERE path='" + path + "'";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                SparkleLogger.LogInfo("CmisDatabase", e.Message);
            }
        }
```

The using statement is disposing the command and not the connection. Try using two nested using statements for each command.

```
   using (var connection= GetSQLiteConnection())
   {
      using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
      {
        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "DELETE FROM folders WHERE path='" + path + "'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            SparkleLogger.LogInfo("CmisDatabase", e.Message);
        }
     }
  }
```

This may alleviate the problem, however other factors could cause this error to manifest.

Comment: After changing to this, it says `Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: SQLiteConnection`

Comment: I don't want to recreate the SQLiteConnection connection everytime, so I can't use this idea, unfortunately.

Comment: I've found that I can totally eliminate this sort of error in my system.data.sqlite code by ensuring that all connections, commands and readers are enclosed in using statements.