# VB.Net SQLite "delayed 25ms for lock/sharing conflict"

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Stress testing insertion of 1 million records in SQLite + VB.net for learning purposes.  Getting the following in my console which seems to be severely limiting my speeds.

> SQLite notice (27): delayed 25ms for lock/sharing conflict at line
>   42982

Btw, I know a transaction would probably be better here but I still would like to know why I am receiving this message.  Also tried the solution from this SO Question, didn't work for me:  [SQLite error (10): delayed 25ms for lock/sharing conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394280/sqlite-error-10-delayed-25ms-for-lock-sharing-conflict)

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()
        Using conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db;Version=3")
            conn.Open()
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO test VALUES (1)", conn)
                For I = 0 To 1000000
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
        sw.Stop()
        Debug.WriteLine("Completed! " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

After digging around the net for a good hour or so, it seems my problem was happening because I use dropbox, and my project (including my sqlite DB) was in my dropbox folder.  When I exited the DropBox app, the console message went away.

With that said, I'll still be using a transaction :P

Comment: Same here. Would've never guessed.